# Is everyone facing the slow internet and intermittent disconnection?

Tags: grammar

- User A: Is everyone facing the slow internet and intermittent disconnection?
- User B: Yes
- User C: Yes
- User D: Yes

---

In the above, are the answers provided by users, B, C, D correct?
Seeing as B, C, D do not represent the complete number of affected people.

Comment: Generally, nobody knows what *everyone* is facing. Were there such a person, the asker would have adressed that one instead of adressing the whole group. But he or she asked the group so that each one gives an answer and thus gather together a more general one. What people answer to report their own situation is a convention. As long as the asker knows each individual  "yes" isn't intended to be a "yes" to the question but rather an "I am", answering "yes" works for the purpose at hand. As with any other convention, the question isn't whether it's right or wrong, but rather if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically B, C and D are wrong, because the question can only be answered by A, and then only after everyone in the group has individually answered *yes* or *no* to the (slightly different) question *Are **you** facing the slow internet and intermittent disconnection?*

As an aside, the question should use **experiencing** and not **facing**.